# How to add an event handler in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, dom

I have a listener on DOMContentLoaded which calls startup() function.

I want to add more listeners (within the startup function) to items added to the DOM in the startup function. But it seems to fail (no click event registetered)

I use `item.addEventListener("click", f, false);` where f is the function that is supposed to run.

NOTE: I CANNOT use onclick=... I also cannot use JQuery.

[Demo code is here](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1h_CjGLd7Ym1NeyuRNjnC3eP29oqCpb9rIQ7_XGbWXAM/edit)

Comment: Show some code and markup, a minimal example will do.

Comment: My code: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1h_CjGLd7Ym1NeyuRNjnC3eP29oqCpb9rIQ7_XGbWXAM/edit

Comment: It is far better to post a minimal example here. It is very likely that in creating the example, you will discover your issue. If not, the example (and probably a solution) will be available for posterity. Otherwise, there will likely be a vague question with a dead link and an incongruent answer.

Comment: Why do you have "false" for third argument?

Comment: @tekknolagi: That argument defines whether the handler should be triggered in the capture or bubble phase. `false` means bubble phase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several issues in your code:

1. `previous` function is not defined
2. To attach a click event via addEventListener, the event name is `click` not `onclick`.
3. You are calling `addListeners` outside of your `load` function.

Here is a jsfiddle that works: http://jsfiddle.net/VUgRu/

You should always use the javascript console to see what errors you are getting.

Answer (score 0):

Using no frameworks (no excuse to use them) and adding an event listener in standard compliant browsers and Internet Explorer 8 and older for attachEvent...

```
 if (window.addEventListener) {document.addEventListener('keydown',keyPressed,false);}
 else {document.attachEvent('onkeydown',keyPressed);}

function keyPressed(evt)
{
 var e = evt || event;
 var key = e.which || e.keyCode;

 switch (key)
 {
  case 77:// M
  alert('m key pressed');
  break;

  case 76://L
  alert('L key pressed');
  break;
 }
}
```